# Drupal login without going to a new page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm aware of the ajax login module but it doesn't do what the name implies. What I need is a way for users to login without the page being refreshed or without being directed to a new page. Is there any way to do this in Drupal?

Comment: Try with Login popup module https://www.drupal.org/project/login_popup

Comment: but does that login without creating a new window session? The video in the tutorial ends just before he clicks login ... I'm pretty sure I've tried this one before.

Comment: and by the way, drupal 7 not drupal 8 (that module is for drupal 8 only).

Comment: Try out this one: https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan

Comment: No where in that module's docs does it describe "login without going to another page." Nonetheless I tried the module and could not get the block to appear to test it out. I'm honestly surprised that there is no module which supports this.

Comment: You can use a login block and alter the login form submit to keep the user on same page.

Comment: pretty sure that will just refresh the page, no? I need to keep the same window session.